# Плавная смена слайдов через исчезновение css

Tags: html, css, keyframes

Есть стандартная разметка на HTML, CSS. Хотел переделать обычный съезд в сторону на плавное появление и исчезновение. Но код упорно шлёт нах... (JS не предлагать)

```css
/* slides */
.slides {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    animation: slide 12s infinite;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    55% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="./img/500107.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/500109.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/501155.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/499713.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Изначальный стиль @keyframes был таким

```
@keyframes slide{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    25%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    30%{
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    55%{
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    75%{
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateX(-300%);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(-300%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Опишите в вопросе что именно у вас не получается, с чем именно возникают сложности и что по вашему мнению работает не так.

Comment: ```Хотел переделать обычный съезд в сторону на плавное появление и исчезновение.```
Основной вопрос по @keyframes, Хочу через появление и исчезновение элементов, сделать слайды. Но если вставляю только этот код, элементы изображений не меняются, а меняется один и тот же файл, первый. Смены как во втором не происходит вообще </br>
```0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }.... ```

Comment: Предложение `Но код упорно шлёт нах` подразумевает что вы что-то пытались сделать, но это никак у вас не получалось...где эти попытки? с чем именно у вас возникли проблемы? Кто именно вас послал?

Comment: вставьте ваш вариант с opacity и опишите что именно там вас не устраивает

Comment: Попытки отслоились вместе с нервами и 7ю часами времени.

Comment: Описал проблему в первом коментарии - 
```Но если вставляю только этот код, элементы изображений не меняются, а меняется один и тот же файл, первый.```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если просто вставить opacity то момент съезда будет видно во время исчезновения изображения, а хочу сделать смену изображений незаметной